# Angular 2 - No provider for Service

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I've been trying to troubleshoot a strange problem with angular 2 where it isn't detecting my provider declaration, but nothing is working. I can't even replicate it in plunkr.

I'm using angular 2 rc 3 with router 3.0 alpha.8.

Error message is: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for TestService!`

app.routes.ts:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './app/home/home.component';
import { LogInComponent } from './app/log-in/log-in.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './app/sign-up/sign-up.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'log-in', component: LogInComponent },
  { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

// enableProdMode();

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
])
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

app/app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { TestService } from './shared/test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div id="menu">
      <a [routerLink]="['/sign-up']"><button>Sign Up</button></a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [TestService]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

app/sign-up/sign-up.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { TestService } from '../shared/test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'sign-up',
  template: `<h1>Sign up!</h1>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SignUpComponent {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
    this.testService.test('works?');
  }


}
```

app/shared/test.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }

  test(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
  }

}
```

So, I'm providing the testservice in the base component (app.component.ts) because I want all my components to access the same instance. However, when I navigate to sign-up, I get the no provider for testservice error. If I provide the TestService within the sign-up component, this then works:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { TestService } from '../shared/test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'sign-up',
  template: `<h1>Sign up!</h1>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [TestService]
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

However, I need the same instance accessible throughout my app, so how can I inject this at the main component level?

I even tried replicating this app-level service providing with plunkr with the same version of everything, but it doesn't seem to give me the same error...

http://plnkr.co/edit/5bpeHs72NrlyUITCAJim?p=preview

Comment: It has to be related to you project config. The code is fine, this is why it runs in Plunker.

Comment: What config do you think may be suspect? I can post my systemjs config if that helps

Comment: I don't know much about systemjs, because I'm only using Dart locally. I'd try to create a new project with angular-cli and copy the code bits there to see if you get the same error.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question. Then you can accept it (after 2 days cool-down phase) which results this question being marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a configuration issue after all, and a completely elusive one at that.

Per the ang2 style guide, I had my main.ts one folder up from my main app folder, and in `systemjs.config` I had to declare the main for app as `'../main.js'`. When I moved the main file to the root app folder and changed the package declaration in systemjs to `'main.js'` it worked.

The odd thing is everything else worked, right up until I try to utilize hierarchical dependency injection.

Answer (score 3):

Injecting something on the `app` level is done in `bootstrap`:

`main.ts`:

```
import { TestService } from '../shared/test.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, TestService
])
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well and it doesn't work either. Besides: "The bootstrap provider option is intended for configuring and overriding Angular's own preregistered services, such as its routing support. The preferred approach is to register application providers in application components."

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser-dynamic/index/bootstrap-function.html. Check `Class export`. It says `customProviders`. It allows anything `@Injectable`.

Comment: Try adding `providers: [TestService]` into `SignUpComponent`

Comment: Yeah, it's allowable to provide in bootstrap but not preferred. That's beside the point though since it still doesn't work. Also, adding providers in sign up component works, but then I can't use the same reference in my other components.

Comment: For global services providing at the root component is the preferred way according to the Angular2 style guide. The new router is required to be provided with bootstrap because of some dependency with `APP_INITIALIZER` but otherwise `bootstrap()` and root component are almost equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

To All future readers - and this is correct for angular 2.0.0 rc-4:

make sure that you follow the below folder structure:

```
root:
index.html
package.json
systemjs.config.js
tsconfig.json (if using TypeScript) 
typings.json
app (folder):
 - main.js (the root script for your app)
 - app.component.js (the root component for the entire app)
```

This is crucial for the hierarchical injection to properly scope and identify providers.

Also, and **this is very important** - if still encountering problems and you are using TypeScript or any other transpiled language- delete any artifacts which your transpiler produces for every associated class in the problematic object graph - this, and the OP's answer eventually helped in my case (*.map.js and *.js files deleted and re-transpiled).

Comment: Wow. I've been going nuts until I found this. I didn't understand why a global registration of a service wasn't recognized by my component. Till I found that hierarchy thing. Thank you.

Comment: mmm. Thought It will help but still ...http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140220/room-for-royi-and-eyal-perry

Answer (score 3):

For me, some references to the "services" folder were "Services". When I made them all "services" (lower case), it worked.

For example:

```
import {ApiService} from "./Services/api.service";
```

didn't work, but this worked:

```
import {ApiService} from "./services/api.service";
```